# which signal will caused "wait_event_interruptible" interrupted?

Tags: linux, drivers, signals, arch-arm

There are wait_event_interruptible in a driver to wait until message is aviliable.But this function was interrupted by a signal.
I find out this in manpage:

> The function will return -ERESTARTSYS if it was interrupted by a signal

Another community tell me the signal is "nonblocked pending signals".

So I want to know what is "nonblocked pending signals"?
And how to find out whitch thread produce this signal?

Could I produce this signal manuly to interrupt "wait_event_interruptible " ?